# Get Max of len(string) in nested dictionary if string can be None

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, nonetype

I'm trying to get the max length of a string from a nested dictionary. The field can be a string or None.

When doing this with a list from a nested dictionary, the following works:

`max_value = max(dict, key=lambda d: len(dict[d]["list_key"]))`

When I run this on the string field, code is:

`max_value = max(dict, key=lambda d: len(dict[d]["string_key"]))`

because the string can be None, I receive the following error:

`TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

How can I incorporate `is not None` into the second function?

Comment: I think `max(dict, key=lambda d: 0 if dict[d]["string_key"] is none else len(dict[d]["string_key"]))` should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on a single lambda expression, something like:

`max_value = max(dict, key=lambda d: len(dict[d]["string_key"]) if dict[d]["string_key"] is not None else 0)`

However this starts to look pretty messy. How about

```
strs = (dict[d]["string_key"] for d in dict)
maxlen = max(len(s) for s in strs if s is not None)
```

Comment: Why use a loop ? You just have to write the key function as a proper function instead of a lambda - and it will be much faster than a plain loop.

Comment: yep, exactly. I guess I meant 'split it up' instead of 'do it in a loop'

Answer (score 2):

please do not use python built-in class/type to name your variables, instead of using `dict` you can use `my_dict`:

```
max_value = max(my_dict, key=lambda k: len(my_dict[k]["string_key"] or ''))
```